# Create Azure Logic App Alert for 24 Hour Period

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic App that processes an email that is received once a day.

I would like to setup an alert on the logic app that notifies me if the "Runs Succeeded" metric occurs less than 1 time in a 24 hour period.  (In other words, the email wasn't received for that day.)  However, the greatest period allowed in the Alert UI is 6 hours, as shown below.

**Is there a work-around to create an alert with a 24 hour period?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered there are two types of alerts in Azure: Classic and regular.  The regular alerts have 12 and 24 hour period options that the classic alerts do not.

Within the context of an Azure Logic App, you can only setup a "classic" alert (as of the time of this post), which has a period limit of 6 hours.

However, performing a search for "alerts" in Azure's services search reveals that there are alerts listed under **Monitor**:

[image]

Inside the **Monitor - Alerts** blade, you'll see two different types of alerts:

[image: Azure Alert options]

Selecting the non-classic alert results in a wizard interface to create the alert and there is a period option for 24 hours:

[image]

Hopefully I never need an alert period longer than 24 hours!